# iOS simulator doesn't launch my app

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native, ios-simulator

I've installed the `create-react-native-app`, however I am facing an issue with my iOS simulator. It launch well but doesn't open my app and stay in the home screen. My android emulator behave as expected and the app is directly displayed. I've installed and updated XCode.
The default device is an iPhone X but if i set to iPhone 6, it still open an iPhone X simulator.

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

Check your deployment target under general properties of your project.

Answer (score 0):

I closed virtual box machine with option "power off the machine".
And then opened it again and started it.
It worked well for me